# "How can I code a 2 dimension array input in Javascript such that it looks like this?"

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, input

Basically what I am trying to do is a Gaussian elimination program in Javascript, so far it works when I enter the coefficient matrix directly in the code, but now that I am trying to let the user input it, I fail.
For instance, if I directly write

```
$A = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]];
```

The program will work alright, however, with my approach at entering a matrix it won´t work.

```
var rows= prompt("Input the number of variables");
                var A = [];
                alert("Input the coefficients of the equations");
                for(var i = 0; i<rows; i++)
                {
                A.push([]);
                A[i].push(new Array(rows));
                for (var j = 0; j<rows; j++)
                {
                    A[i][j]= prompt()
                }
                }
            }
```

Is there a way to code it correctly?

Comment: What isn't working? I just tried it and it seems to work fine, minus the extra `}` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only issue appears to be an extra `}` at the end of the code. Perhaps reformatting with consistent paragraph indentations would illuminate this kind of error in the future. See the working code below.

```js
var rows = prompt("Input the number of variables");

var A = [];

alert("Input the coefficients of the equations");

for(var i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
  A.push([]);
  A[i].push(new Array(rows));
  for (var j = 0; j<rows; j++) {
    A[i][j]= prompt()
  }
}

console.log(A);
```